# TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] python socket and gui tkinter server connects to the client

Tags: python, sockets, tkinter, server, timeout

```
from tkinter import *
import _thread
from typing import TextIO

#页面代码
root = Tk()
root.title('TPC服务端')
root.geometry('640x480')

label_1 = Label(root,relief=GROOVE,text='从客户端接收的数据')
label_1.place(relx=0.1,rely=0.0,relwidth=0.4,relheight=0.1)
Operate = Text(root,relief=GROOVE)
Operate.place(relx=0.1,rely=0.1,relwidth=0.4,relheight=0.4)


Tips = Text(root,relief=GROOVE)
Tips.place(relx=0.1,rely=0.5,relwidth=0.4,relheight=0.4)
Tips.insert(END,'当前状态:\n')
Tips.configure(state=DISABLED)

root.mainloop()

class TCPServer():
    def __init__(self):
        self.HOST = '192.0.0.1'
        self.PORT = 8080
        self.BUFSIZ = 1024
        self.ADDRESS = (self.HOST,self.PORT)
        self.tcpServerSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
        self.tcpServerSocket.bind(self.ADDRESS) #IP地址和固定端口信息 
        self.tcpServerSocket.listen(5)
    def try_connect(self):
            global var
            var='服务器正在运行，等待客户端连接...\n'
            Tips.insert(END,var)
            Tips.configure(state=DISABLED)
            while True:
                var='服务器正在运行，等待客户端连接...\n'
                Tips.configure(state=NORMAL)
                Tips.insert(END,var)
                Tips.configure(state=DISABLED)
                self.client_socket, self.client_address = self.tcpServerSocket.accept()
                var='客户端{}已连接！\n'.format(self.client_address)
                Tips.configure(state=NORMAL)
                Tips.insert(END,var)
                Tips.configure(state=DISABLED)
                
                while True:
                    self.data = self.client_socket.recv(self.BUFSIZ)
                    if(self.data):
                        var='接收到消息 {}({} bytes) 来自 {}\n'.format(self.data.decode('utf-8'), len(self.data), self.client_address)
                            # 返回响应数据，接受的数据不做处理即返回
                        self.client_socket.send(self.data)
                        var='发送消息 {} 至 {}\n'.format(self.data.decode('utf-8'), self.client_address)
                        Tips.configure(state=NORMAL)
                        Tips.insert(END,var)
                        Tips.configure(state=DISABLED)
                        Operate.configure(state=NORMAL)
                        Operate.insert(END,self.data)
                        Operate.configure(state=DISABLED)
                    else:
                        var='客户端 {} 已断开！\n'.format(self.client_address)
                        Tips.configure(state=NORMAL)
                        Tips.insert(END,var)
                        Tips.configure(state=DISABLED)
                        break
            # 关闭socket
            self.client_socket.close()       
            # 取消监听socket，自此拒绝响应其它客户端
            self.tcpServerSocket.close()
Server = TCPServer()

_thread.start_new_thread(Server.try_connect)
root.mainloop()
```

![text]([enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oEQqb.png)
I want to know why such a mistake happened.I am using python to make a simple network communication program.It contains both the client and server sides.This is my client program code.
I am a beginner.
The server connects to the client .i use vscode to write the code.I use python 3.10

Comment: Normally a new thread will be created to communicate with the connected client so that the server can wait for connection from other clients.

Comment: The code starts from `class TCPServer()` will not be executed until the root window is closed because of the line `root.mainloop()` before `class TCPServer()`.  So there is no TCP server running at all.  After removing that line, a simple TCP socket client can connect to the server successfully.  Note that I have tested using `127.0.0.1` instead of `192.0.0.1`.

Comment: Dear Mr.acw1668.Your valuable suggestion makes me successfully solved the problem.I sincerely thank you.You let me know this newcomer to the warmth of the community！